# DataBound controls loading images and avoiding image cache in WP7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, caching, memory

I want to load images into a Pivot header to substitute the lack of a Gallery control in WP7. I'm trying to populate them from a URL, and want to make sure that the image is not kept in the cache (by setting UriSource = null) to make sure that they don't take too much resources.

There's no way to do this in the XAML itself, can someone give me sample code to handle this from code-behind. my attempts have been unsuccessful. what am I doing wrong here?

```
public class PhotoGalleryVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Images
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> list = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
            foreach (RoomImage r in App.appData.currentChoices.roomImages)
            {
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Uri.UnescapeDataString(r.largeUri)));
                img.UriSource = null;
                list.Add(img); 
            }

            return list;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option that enables to ignore image cache:

```
 bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```

Read more at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: not sure if it did anything, the memory allocated and returned were pretty much similar for even large images used.